# Mutex c# Safe handle has been closed

Tags: c#, .net, mutex

Here is my code to make a method call mutually exlcussive

```
public class X
{
    private static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MutexForFile");
    public IList<string> DoIt(IList<string> documents)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        if (mutex.WaitOne())
        {
            using (var agent = new MyClass())
            {
                // operation login
                if (agent.LibraryLogon("**", "***"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //codes to access shared resource
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.ErrorFormat("");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (!mutex.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed)
                        {
                            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                        }
                        mutex.Dispose();
                    }
                    Log.DebugFormat("Completed");

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to Login Session");
                }
            }
            Log.DebugFormat("Completed Do it");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I am forced to do the check **if (!mutex.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed)** as I got ObjectDisposedException saying  "Safe handle has been closed" when I call  mutex.ReleaseMutex().

Is it the right way to avoid this  exception?

Do any once can suggest any pitfals or issues with this codes?

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation for the Mutex class on MSDN for the constructors.  Specifically `Mutex(bool initiallyOwned, string name)` and `Mutex(bool initiallyOwned, string name, out bool creatNew)`  The easiest fix might be to initialize your mutex with intiallyOwned = false, rather than true.  You should then be able to drop the if block in your finally statement.  I haven't verified this, and it's been a long time since I've used the .Net mutex, however, I think this will solve the problem.  Depending on your full usage of the mutex, you may have to do a bit more handling.

Comment: Documentation for convenience: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Mutex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I had tried this ,but that had not helped me

Comment: After you called mutex.Dispose(), you can never use class X again.  You do anyway, that's what causes the exception.  You are also fumbling the ReleaseMutex() call, it *must* be called unconditionally after you called WaitOne().  The code is fundamentally broken in more than one way, clearly you'll have to rethink this.

Comment: How should I rearrage this codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid disposing the mutex while another thread is waiting for it:

```
Thread #1: WaitOne() -> gets ownership
Thread #2: WaitOne() -> waits for thread #1
Thread #1: ReleaseMutex() -> causes thread #2 to continue
Thread #1: Dispose()
Thread #2: ReleaseMutex() -> mutex was disposed by thread #1
```

The `SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed` just prevents the exception from appearing, but does not solve the underlying issue. It can only be solved in the code which spawns these threads, not within the thread - and perhaps you should not have multiple threads attempting to log in simultaneously?

Comment: I could see similar thing at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex.aspx

Comment: I am not sure where should I call ReleaseMutex and Dispose methods.Can any one show me that?

Comment: @KuttanSujith I don't know the reason why you need the `Mutex` in the first place - why are you trying to let multiple threads perform this operation?

Comment: @  C.Evenhuis:Multiple threads should not perform this operation.that is why I am using mutex

Comment: @KuttanSujith If this method _should_ be performed by multiple threads, but one at a time, you should only `ReleaseMutex` each time, and only `Dispose` it at the end of your program.

Comment: @KuttanSujith But if the method should only be performed exactly once, you'd better change the code that instructs these threads to perform the operation.

Comment: How should I know "the end of my program" ?

Comment: @KuttanSujith The garbage collector will automatically dispose of the `Mutex`, I did not mean to emphasise "the end of your program" like that, I just wanted to illustrate that you should _not_ dispose the `Mutex` unless you are sure you won't use it again.

Comment: Your comments helps me.I will restructure my code like 1.remove the dispose call 2.move the releasemutex at the last line of if(waitone())

Comment: Based on C.Evenhuis comments  I have made my finally as                                     'finally {mutex.ReleaseMutex();} 'and created a Dispose method seperatly as 'public void Dispose()
        {
            if (null != mutex)
            {
                mutex.Dispose();
            }
        }'